# SharePoint Online List Settings - Forms Setting not available in the Settings menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have a couple lists on a SPO site that do not get the "Forms Settings" option under List Settings. It is under Integrate, and I have successfully created new PowerApp forms for a couple lists and they work fine. Although, since I do not appear to have that specific setting, I cannot manage it from the list level (Like reverting back to default).

Every other list has this option in it, except all the lists on this site.

This site is a private channel from a Team, as that seems likely why. Although I have no idea why it would let me customize the forms, yet not even show me that menu option in actual List Settings.

I CAN get to it if I add FormSettings.aspx? to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is the [Private channel limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/private-channels#private-channel-limitations) and Microsoft is working on full apps support for private channels.

As you said, add FormSettings.aspx? to the URL is the workaround for now.

Similar issue for your reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/forms-in-a-private-channel-in-teams/m-p/1072209